# Create a different loop pointer address

Tags: c

I have a code where I pass the values ​​of a pointer to different groups

The value is repeated for some groups

So I need to create a new address every time a new id is read

I want to keep using calloc

**Code:**

```
struct Block {
    int id;  
};

struct MySettings {
    int conf_id;
    int group;
    int enable;
    bool hide_name;
    bool login_persistence;
    bool remove_cache;
    struct Block *block;
};


struct MySettings *Settings[50];

void read_db(void) {
    struct MySettings *st;
    char str[80];
    int count_block = 0;

    for(int i = 0; i < 10; i++) {
        st = (struct MySettings*)calloc(1, sizeof(struct MySettings));

        st->conf_id = i;

        st->hide_name = true;
        st->login_persistence = true;
        st->remove_cache = true;

        st->block = (struct Block*)realloc(st->block, ++count_block * sizeof(struct Block));
        st->block[count_block-1].id = i+1;      
            
        
        struct MySettings *st2;
        st2 = (struct MySettings*)calloc(1, sizeof(struct MySettings)); 
        st2 = st;
        st2->group = GetGroupID(i);
        st2->enable = true;

        Settings[st->group] = st2;
    }

    clear();    
}

void clear(void) {
for(int i = 0; i < 50; i++) {
    if(Settings[i]) {
        if(Settings[i]->block)
            free(Settings[i]->block);
    
        free(Settings[i]);
        Settings[i] = NULL;
    }
}
```

}

In `st2->group` the id for each group is defined

This ID is different for each reading

I need that at each reading the memory address is different for each group

To understand better I need all generated ids to have the same settings

Each configuration generated with a different ID must be a different address

What's the best way to do this?

Comment: General Note: In C, there is no need to cast the return of `malloc` (or `calloc` or `realloc`), it is unnecessary. See: [Do I cast the result of malloc?](http://stackoverflow.com/q/605845/995714). Never `realloc` to the original pointer, use a temporary instead, e.g. `void *tmp = realloc (mypointer, ...); if (!tmp) { /* handle error */ } else { mypointer = tmp; }`. Otherwise ***when*** `realloc` fails returning `NULL` you overwrite your original pointer address creating a memory leak.

Comment: Instead of `st = (struct MySettings*)calloc(1, sizeof(struct MySettings));` use `st = calloc (1, sizeof *st);` using the dereferenced pointer to set type-size. (eliminates the possibility of getting it wrong)

Comment: I'm still confused on the question. You say each **reading**, but I don't see anywhere you read anything in the code? You loop 1 -> 10 where it looks like you want to do something like `while (/* read the db record */) { /* calloc a new Settings, set values */ ...` You also talk about passing pointers, but you declare a global array of pointers (`Settings`) which isn't passed anywhere? Can you provide [A Minimal Complete Reproducable Example](https://stackoverflow.com/help/minimal-reproducible-example)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Your code seems much more complex than needed. For instance you don't need both `st` and `st2`. Further the line `st2 = st;` overwrites the value of `st2` and you have lost the just allocated memory (i.e. memory leak). Further, `count_block` isn't needed as you already have the counter `i`.

Try like:

```
for(int i = 0; i < 10; i++) {
    struct MySettings *st = calloc(1, sizeof *st);

    st->conf_id = i;

    st->hide_name = true;
    st->login_persistence = true;
    st->remove_cache = true;

    st->block = realloc(st->block, (i + 1) * sizeof *st->block);
    st->block[i].id = i+1;      
        
    st->group = GetGroupID(i);
    st->enable = true;

    Settings[st->group] = st;
}
```

Note 1: In real code you would (in most cases) check that `calloc`, `realloc` didn't return NULL

Note 2: While it's not illegal in this code, it's a bit strange to use `realloc`. Use of `malloc` (or `calloc`) would be more natural.

Note 3: `st->block[i].id = i+1;` seems strange. It only sets the `id` of the last element. But it may be what is needed.

Comment: I think that is more what the op is aiming for, though same note on using a temporary for `st->block = realloc(st->block, ...` and unless `st->block` is initialized `NULL`, `realloc()` can't be used for the initial allocation. (but I'm somewhat confused on the "block" thing to begin with...)

Comment: @DavidC.Rankin Well, `st->block` **is** NULL due to use of `calloc`. But I agree that `realloc` is strange. See note 2.

Comment: Yes, that is correct -- so the initial allocation with `realloc()` is fine there `:)` (we will let some other pedant argue the `calloc` initialization and `NULL` are different -- `0` is `0` to me... until we get `nullptr` in C23...

Comment: It works, but when using clear it is showing an error in invalid pointer to `Settings[i]->block`

Comment: @DavidC.Rankin :-) True. The really pedantic approach is to say that `calloc` can't initialize to NULL according to the standard. It can't even initialize signed integers.... but today it will be hard to find any computer where it would fail. But I guess you are correct... the pedantic comment has to come :-)

Comment: @Michael the `clear` issue sounds like the uninitialized elements spoken of in the answer....

Comment: @Michael Are you executing some other code that isn't posted here?

Comment: @Michael No problem here https://ideone.com/SmSKMk

Comment: @Michael For the clear problem you could ask a new question and post the code that you have now

Comment: something was missing in the calloc change I made, it works

Comment: @SupportUkraine One question, what if I had a new loop in `group` and `enable` within the existing loop, the address would be the same for all readings of group and `enable` within that `loop` right? Would it be possible to leave the address different?

Comment: @Michael I don't fully understand the question in your comment. But in general you need a call of malloc/calloc to be sure to get a new address

Comment: @SupportUkraine An example https://ideone.com/RzrARB

Comment: @Michael BTW: realloc when called with NULL will also result in a new address

Comment: @Michael I think you should ask a new question but.... In the ideone code you keep storing **the same** `st` into different elements of `Settings`. Consequently when you call `clear` you will call `free` on the same pointer several times. That's a bug. Allocate once, free once.

Answer (score 0):

To ensure that each configuration generated with a different ID is a different address, you need to allocate memory for each configuration separately. Currently, in your code, you are reallocating the memory for the block array within the same MySettings object. Instead, you can create a new MySettings object for each configuration and allocate memory separately for the block array,as follow:

```
void read_db(void) {
    char str[80];
    int count_block = 0;

    for(int i = 0; i < 10; i++) {
        struct MySettings *st;
        st = (struct MySettings*)calloc(1, sizeof(struct MySettings));

        st->conf_id = i;

        st->hide_name = true;
        st->login_persistence = true;
        st->remove_cache = true;

        st->block = (struct Block*)calloc(++count_block, sizeof(struct Block));
        st->block[count_block-1].id = i+1;      
            
        
        struct MySettings *st2;
        st2 = (struct MySettings*)calloc(1, sizeof(struct MySettings)); 
        *st2 = *st;
        st2->group = GetGroupID(i);
        st2->enable = true;

        Settings[st->group] = st2;
        
        // free memory allocated for st
        free(st->block);
        free(st);
    }

    clear();    
}
```

Comment: See comments under original question regarding casting the return of `calloc`.